# QtCreator is unable to use the Android kit

Tags: android, qt, qt5, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I installed android `sdk` , `ndk` and `emulator` in Kubuntu 18.04 and added the following configurations for `Android` device :

[image]
And there were no errors.

Then I added a kit with the following configuration (Although it had to automatically do this , but that didn't happen) :

[image]

But now I'm unable to use that kit in the `New project` wizard :

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : QtCreator also cannot list my `AVD` in `AVD Manager`.
I can run `emulator -avd AVD` from terminal without any trouble.So that's not the cause of the problem.
This is the output of `sdkmanager --list` about installed packages :

[image]

Comment: At least "device type", "device" and "Qt version" look wrong in the kit configuration. But more importantly i don't see an NDK configured?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld "Default Android NDK directory structure is correct" This is what it says.There's currently no errors in the window.I had manually added the NDK location before . And I added information about the installed versions to the question.